# Displaying Several LinkedIn Profile Images using Advanced Custom Fields (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a section of a site running on WP that uses a custom post type and Advanced Custom Fields and need to be able to do the following:

In an ACF field, paste a person's LinkedIn URL or username, which displays their profile image. The markup in the template would look something like...

```
<img src="<?php the_field('linkedin_profile_pic'); ?>" alt="">
```

The problem is that every plugin that I've encountered only allows the LinkedIn data to be pulled from the account I used to obtain the API key. I'm thinking that because of the security restrictions, pulling anyone's profile pic (a unique one for each post) isn't doable.

Any suggestions or direction would be greatly appreciated.